# CSS: page content not filling entire screen

Tags: css

the content is not filling the entire page even though it is set to 100% height

Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/SB67f/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="head">
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="box">1
    </div>
    <div class="box">2
    </div>
    <div class="box">3
    </div>
    <div class="box">4
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
html
{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    min-height:100%;
}
div#content
{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: #dcf0f7;
}
div#head
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#5e9dc8;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
div#footer
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#5e9dc8;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
div#content div.box
{
    background:#0c2c52;
    color:white;
    height:15px;
    width:300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

I do not understand why the  is not covering the entire screen instead of just reaching to the last element within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the height for both the html and body elements:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
```

And also set the height of the #content div to 100%:

```
div#content {
height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SB67f/2/

Bear in mind as you have set your header and footer to `position:fixed;`, setting your `#content` div to 100% height will result in some overflow vertically as `position:fixed;` takes the aforementioned elements out of the natural page flow!

Answer (score 2):

`html, body` needs both `height:100%; min-height:100%`. Also the `content` div needs `min-height:100%`. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SB67f/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the content div you need height:100% on it as well as html and body

```
div#content {
    height:100%;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: #dcf0f7;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SB67f/5/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/SB67f/7/

```
*
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
html
{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    height:100%;
}
div#content
{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: #dcf0f7;
    height:inherit;
}
div#head
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#5e9dc8;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
div#footer
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#5e9dc8;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
div#content div.box
{
    background:#0c2c52;
    color:white;
    height:15px;
    width:300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

replaced min-height: 100%; to height: 100%; on body and set div#content height as inherit